# Validation number in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make validation in jQuery in order to input only a number not text. But i dont know how to do it.

```
\$('#id_form').validate(
 {
  rules: {
   name: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
   surname: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    gender: {
      required: true
    },
   pId: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    dId: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    }
      },
 highlight: function(element) {
    \$(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
  },
  success: function(element) {
    element
    .text('').addClass('valid')
    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
  }
 });
```

pId snd dId should be numbers, if not display a meessage

Comment: Do you use http://jqueryvalidation.org/?

Comment: Is this purely for desktop? and [since you are using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) .. assuming you are in a version at or above 1.7, use that in the keyup, use a custom event handler, whatever suits you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate as integer use `digits: true` in rule ([see docs for list of validator rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/))

```
rules: {
    ...
    pId: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true,
        digits: true
    },
    dId: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true,
        digits: true
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code for only accept the number:

```
if ((/[^0-9\-\(\)\.\_\+\ ]/.test(number))) {
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblError").empty();              
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblError").append(var_IsNumericContactnowithCh);
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
}
```